# Allow the RSU to receive a message from vehicles?

Tags: omnet++, veins

In my VANET simulation, I use (Veins 4.7.1, Inet4 and OMNeT++ 5.4.1) , when starting simulation, each vehicle broadcast a hello message, and while receiving the message from the RSU, during the processing of message, i have a problem that

> "Packet was not detected by the card, power was under sensitivity
>   threshold"

why ?
I want to receive the vehicle message correctly from the RSU, how ?
How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells you, the power was not high enough in order to decode the transmission. This could be because of the distance between the two nodes, because of obstacles like buildings or just because the configuration of the simulation (txPower, minPowerLevel, ...) prevents this. Of course you can just change the configuration of your simulation and get everything working. However, this might not be realistic anymore. The better approach would be to figure out why the signal is too weak.

Comment: thank you thardes2 for answering my question, i have changed the simulation configuration ,but nothing happened:
                                                                                                           *.**.nic.mac1609_4.txPower = 37mW
*.**.nic.mac1609_4.bitrate = 6Mbps
*.**.nic.phy80211p.sensitivity = -89dBm

*.**.nic.phy80211p.useThermalNoise = true
*.**.nic.phy80211p.thermalNoise = -110dBm

Is there a set of values of this parameters?

Comment: It is impossible to give you a set of parameters.... Easy solution would be to decrease the distance between your nodes. With this there is no need to change parameters

Comment: thank you thardes2, If the problem is only in the distance, I will reduce the distance between the RSUs and vehicles.